# Extracting the number of observations and the modes of random effects from a mer object

Tags: r, random-effects, lmer

I have a `mer` object created with a called to `lmer()`.

I can obtain the random effects with `ranef()` but I would also like to have corresponding number of observations for each random effect - is there an easy way to do that ?

**Additional Info:**

I may not have made myself quite clear above. For example, if I have a simple 2-level model with patients clustered within hospitals and random intercepts for hospitals, I would like to extract the random effects for each hospital with `ranef()` *together* with the number of patients within each hospital. At the moment, I use

```
ranef(fullmodel)[[1]]
```

which gives me something like:

```
     (Intercept)
ADE -0.108195883
BEJ -0.005761677
CIS  0.124129426
CMH  0.270879048
CSI  0.285344837
CUL  0.189308979
```

I would like to get something like:

```
     (Intercept)  n
ADE -0.108195883  77
BEJ -0.005761677  171
CIS  0.124129426  201
CMH  0.270879048  39
CSI  0.285344837  171
CUL  0.189308979  131
```

To do this, I have been using

```
fullmodel <- glmer(.....+(1|hospital), data=dt1)

freqs <- as.data.frame(table(dt1$hospital))
freqs <- freqs[foo$Freq>0,]
```

And then `cbind`ing this to the results from `ranef(fullmodel)[[1]]`

However this seems unsophisticated and prone to error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ranef` returns a list of matrices corresponding to grouping factors, where the rows in each matrix correspond to observations (factor levels) for a random effect and the columns correspond to random effect variables (intercept, slope etc.).  Thus the easiest way to get the numbers of observations is

```
sapply(ranef(model),nrow)
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear in the OP.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

This command returns the random effects together with frequencies of the random factor levels:

```
lapply(names(ranef(model)),
       function(x) cbind(ranef(model)[[x]], table(model.frame(model)[[x]])))
```

Comment: I'm not wild about using `@frame`; would you be willing to use `model.frame(model)` instead ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Agreed, I modified my answer.